# How to replace a matchgroup in sed with different string?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to search in a file and replace all found paths to HTML-files with the path to the file and a hash.

I want to search for something like this:

```
templateUrl: 'path/to/the/file/file.html';
```

I want to replace the file name like this:

```
templateUrl: 'path/to/the/file/file.HASH.html';
```

I already looked at similar questions about this. Currently i have a sed 'draft', which do not works as expected:

```
sed '/templateUrl:/s|/[\.html);]\+|HASH.html|' myFile
```

This replaces the string mentioned above to `templateUrl: 'pathHASH.htmlo/the/file/file.html';`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$ sed 's/^\(templateUrl:.*\)\(\.html\)/\1.HASH\2/' <<< "templateUrl: 'path/to/the/file/file.html';"
templateUrl: 'path/to/the/file/file.HASH.html';
```

First part beginning with `templateUrl:` upto `.html` and following `.html` string are captured and `.HASH` is inserted between the captured strings.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
echo "templateUrl: 'path/to/the/file/file.html';" |sed -r 's@([^.]+)(.*)@\1.HASH\2@g'
templateUrl: 'path/to/the/file/file.HASH.html';
```